# How to delete rows in the table of 10 rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

It is necessary to delete certain rows from the table, but it is necessary to delete not at once, but in a cycle of 10-15 rows.
Lines over ~ 200,000.
Is my code correct?

```sql
FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM INVENTORY_C WHERE ROWNUM < 10) LOOP
  DELETE FROM INVENTORY_C WHERE AVAIL_DATE > sysdate +1;
  vCT := vCT + 1;
  IF MOD(vCT,200000) = 0 THEN
    COMMIT;
```

Comment: You're not using `t` anywhere, your delete isn't restricted. How could it be correct? (Also, why are you trying to make this as slow as possible?)

Comment: Why do you need to delete in batches of 10? Especially if you're not committing until every 200,000 rows? Why not delete in batches of 200,000?

Comment: This is the specificity of the site.
Records somewhere 201000
It is necessary to delete and see what will happen.

Comment: Your requirements aren't very clear here, and the code definitely doesn't even closely match what you say you are trying to do.

Comment: Also you're committing every 200,000 times around the loop, so up to 2,000,000 rows at a time. Please edit your question to explain the problem you are actually trying to solve. Do you want to delete all rows with that future date, but 10 (?) rows at a time, and commit.. how often? Why do you want to do them in batches, and why - if this is the case - different batch sizes for the delete and the commit? At the moment this doesn't really make much sense so it's hard to offer advice...

Comment: @AlexPoole I have a table where there is a column "AVAIL_DATE", I need to delete the rows where the condition "AVAIL_DATE> sysdate +1" is met, but they cannot be deleted all at once. It is necessary to delete 10 lines with a delay of 10 seconds and look at the site that everything is in order with the information - this is done for insurance in order not to lose data or lock the table.

Comment: At 10 lines per 10 seconds 200,000 rows would take about 2.3 days to delete.  Are you sure you don't want to rethink this process?

Comment: @Nick deleting all the records in one go is far safer than doing them in batches IMO, when it comes to risk of deleting the wrong rows. Also `sysdate + 1` did you mean that, or do you mean `trunc(sysdate) + 1`? Because running the former would only delete rows a day ahead of the current date and time, whereas the latter would delete everything beyond the following day at midnight. The former would not delete all rows that were > 24 hours from the first point you started running the query.